# Must a function squeezed by two polynomials be necessarily a polynomial?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, polynomials

Let $f(x)$ be squeezed by $\frac{x}{2} \le f(x) \le x^2 -2x +5$. Must the function $f(x) $ squeezed between these two polynomials  be necessarily a polynomial?

Comment: Well it depends on the context. I don't see any context for the problem ... But I guess the answer is no.

Comment: For example, $x-1\le x-\sin x\le x+1$.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something given by a formula, consider for instance
$$
f(x)=|x|^{3/2}.
$$
It satisfies 
$$
\tfrac x2<f(x)<x^2-2x+5
$$
for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

This function works, is $C^1$, but is not a polynomial:
$$
f(x)= \begin{cases} 4 & x \le 1 \\x^2 -2x +5 & x \ge 1 \end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider

$$f(x)\le g(x)\le h(x)$$ and two arbitrary functions $\phi(x), \psi(x)>0$. Then

$$g(x)=\dfrac{\phi(x)f(x)+\psi(x)h(x)}{\phi(x)+\psi(x)}$$ satisfies the inequalities.

Comment: I'd be clearer if you wrote $g(x)\le f(x)\le h(x)$. The function in the middle in OP's formulation is $f$.

Comment: @fhl: nope, alphabetic order has advantages.